# If a Map has only one member, how to get it without looping if you don't know the key?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it true the only way to get value of a Map when it has only one member and you don't know the key is with a looping construct of some kind that iterates the map?

or is there some kind of shorthand myMap.item(0) sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option ES6 spread operator and index of [0][1] without using key

```js
var map = new Map()
map.set('contra', 'Asynchronous flow control')

console.log([...map][0][1])
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zaerbX

**Explanation:**

**[...map]** will provide array of array with key,value i.e **[['contra', 'Asynchronous flow control']]**
**[...map][0]**  will provide key value array - **['contra', 'Asynchronous flow control']**
**[...map][0][0]** gets key i.e **'contra'**  and
**[...map][0][1]** gets value without using key i.e **'Asynchronous flow control'**

Answer (score 1):

Entries in a Map are sorted by insertion time and can also be iterated as such with `keys()`, `values()` and `entries()`, just like every iterable.

> or is there some kind of myMap.item(0) sort of thing?

That can be easily polyfilled:

```
Map.prototype.item = function(index) {
  let done, value;
  const iterator = this.values();
  do {
    ({done, value} = iterator.next());
  } while(!done && index-- > 0)
  return value;
};
```

Or a bit simpler:

```
Map.prototype.item = function(index) {
  return [...this][index];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A map is an iterable. According to [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map),

> A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order

It is supposed to be iterated in order for specific item to be reached. So `[...myMap][0][1]` actually does this, it iterates the entire map and converts it to an array, which is not very efficient way.

A slightly more efficient way may be to iterate over map keys instead:

```
myMap.get([...myMap.keys()][0])
```

And more efficient way is to not iterate a map entirely and stop iteration when an item is reached, e.g. with `for..of`:

```
let item;
let i = 0;
for (const key of myMap.keys()) {
  if (i === 0) {
    item = myMap.get(key);
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Unless this happens in performance-critical place, this can be considered preliminary optimization. Even then, there may be more efficient way to store data considering this requirement, for instance, with `Map` subclass, or by using regular array or `Set` - if a key doesn't matter but an index does, it's possible that wrong entity was chosen as a key.

Comment: Why do you even use a `for` and `if` if you exit at the first iteration?! You are also missing a `[0]` in the second snippet, and even then it makes no sense as you could just use `values().next().value`

Comment: This answer ignores the question, which is how to do this without iteration.  What I was looking for was the one line solution like that provided by the accepted answer.

Comment: @JonasW. I've made that for illustrative purposes. The solution isn't hard-coded to a map with one entry. Iterating the values manually like you did will surely be more efficient. Thanks for noticing `[0]`.

Comment: @user1023110 note that the spread operator (`...`) actually iterates the Map, so no, the accepted answer does iterate the whole object.

Comment: @user1023110 You cannot do that without iteration. I've provided the explanation for that. The accepted answer *does iteration*, so does `[...myMap][0][1]` that is also mentioned here. `[...myMap]` iterates through the whole map. If you have 1000 entries, all of them will be iterated, even if you need the first one.

Comment: @estus, I understand what you are saying. I should have been more explicit that what was looking for was a way to get the value of a map of size 1 without writing a looping construct.  i.e. if (mymap.size==1) {return [...mymap][0][1];} seems like a pretty elegant solution.  I understand that it will iterate, but I only call it when there is only one object in the map, so its trival.  When there are multiple objects I will have to iterate anyway to find the one I'm looking for.

Comment: @user1023110 I see. For multiple entries skipping the rest of the entries will be beneficial, and the most efficient way is to call iterator manually with `next()`, like [Jonas W showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51117856/3731501) (although for.. of is pretty fast, too).

Answer (score -1):

A map is a dictionary of key value pairs. So to get a value you need to use [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the value by key.

```js
var map1 = new Map();
map1.set('bar', 'foo');
map1.set('cat', 'dog');

console.log(map1.get('bar'))
console.log(map1.get('cat'))
```

If you need to get the value by id, then a Map probably isn't the right solution for your data, in which case an array of objects might be better.